# Where put receivers (methods) in Go?

Tags: go, methods

There is a recommended way where put receivers in Go when we have multiple structs in one file?

Option A: Methods after each struct

```
Buyer struct {
    // omitted code
}

func (s *Buyer) Buy() {
    // omitted code
}

Seller struct {
    // omitted code
}

func (s *Seller) Sell() {
    // omitted code
}
```

Option B: Methods after all structs

```
Buyer struct {
    // omitted code
}

Seller struct {
    // omitted code
}

func (s *Buyer) Buy() {
    // omitted code
}

func (s *Seller) Sell() {
    // omitted code
}
```

Comment: This is not a recommendation *for* or *against* but, there's also option C "one method per file" used, for example, in some parts of the docker project ([link](https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/master/client)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language spec allows you to put them anywhere in the same package (you can put them in different files too but must be in the same package). [Spec: Method declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)

> A receiver base type cannot be a pointer or interface type and **it must be defined in the same package as the method**.

Other than that it's just common sense. Put them close (next) to the receiver type (which is Option A in your question). Easier to find, easier to maintain.